# Is it possible ot use placeholder inside curly brackets?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use {....} with string.Format?

```
var test = "{value: {0}}";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(test, 10));
```

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to escape `{` and `}` is to duplicate them:

```
var test = "{{value: {0}}}";
```

will print `{value: 10}`

The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.7.2#escaping-braces), and also lists a useful alternative:

```
string.Format("{0}{1:D}{2}", "{", value, "}");
```